# mount_webdav https with NSTask with user credentials

Tags: objective-c, macos, webdav, nstask

I was trying to mount a webdav share (Windows Server 2008r2) over NSTask. But had no luck.

```
    NSString *server = @"https://domain;username:password@SERVER.tld:443/WDAV";
    NSString *mountpoint = @"/Users/me/Desktop/MountPoint";

    NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
    task.launchPath = @"/sbin/mount_webdav";
    task.arguments = @[server, mountpoint];


    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];

    int status = [task terminationStatus];
    if (status == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Mounted to Server");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Mounted to Server failed with status code: %i", status);
    }
```

Exit Code is always `22`.

When I try to connect over Terminal then I use `/sbin/mount_webdav -i "https://SERVER.tld:443/WDAV" "/Users/me/Desktop/MountPoint"`

An prom appear where I must type username in my case `domain\username` and password. Works fine over Terminal, but over NSTask I have no idea.